# Delete .Bak Files from UNC Share paths by Using STored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to delete .Bak files from Network share path.
Please find my code below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SPDeleteOldBackupFiles] (  
 @BackupFolderLocation VARCHAR(1000)  
,@FilesSuffix VARCHAR(3)  
,@DaysToDelete SMALLINT  
)  
AS  
BEGIN  
 DECLARE @delCommand VARCHAR(1000)  

 IF UPPER (@FilesSuffix) IN ('BAK','TRN')   
 BEGIN  
  SET @delCommand = CONCAT('FORFILES /p ' ,  
    @BackupFolderLocation,  
    ' /s /m '  ,  
    '*.'   ,   
    @FilesSuffix ,  
    ' /d '  ,  
    '-'   ,   
    ltrim(Str(@DaysToDelete)),  
    ' /c ' ,  
    '"'  ,  
    'CMD /C del /Q /F @FILE',  
    '"')  

  PRINT @delCommand  
  EXEC sys.xp_cmdshell @delCommand  
 END  
END
```

above Stored procedure giving error like below ,

> ERROR: UNC paths (\machine\share) are not supported.

Please help me for above bug , 
I same site I saw below answer , please help me to add below ting to my Stored procedure

NET USE V: \devexpress\C$
Forfiles -p V:\FULL\ -s -m *.* -d -7 -c "cmd /c del /q @path"

Comment: `ERROR: UNC paths (\machine\share) are not supported.` pretty clear... don't use a UNC path. Try mapping a drive instead.

Comment: I want to delete from share , that is some bulk operation , can you please send script for UNC path

Comment: I think maybe you aren't understanding what `not supported` means. That means you cannot use a UNC in this way. *Map a drive to the UNC and use the mapped drive instead*

Comment: SSIS is the right tool for the job in this situation.

Comment: From share is there any mapping to detect drive automatically from share path ????